# Cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'string' so my Item Id is shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

In my `ItemController`, I have:

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    ItemViewModel objItemViewModel = new ItemViewModel();
    objItemViewModel.ListItemId = (from objItem in objShopOnlineDBEntities.Items
                                                    select new SelectListItem()
                                                    {
                                                        Value = objItem.ItemId.ToString(),
                                                        Selected = true
                                                    });
    return View(objItemViewModel);
}
```

and to show in the view :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        Item Id :
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemId, new SelectList(Model.ListItemId, "Value", "Text" ), new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't let me show the item id. I have similar thing but for Category ID and I have selected the value of the category id 1 and to show me the name of that category id for example Men. That works just fine, but for id I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` but not `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemId, 
    new SelectList(Model.ListItemId, "Value", "Text" ), 
    new { @class = "form-control"})
```

While in your controller, you miss out the `Text` property for the `SeletListItem`.

```cs
objItemViewModel.ListItemId = (from objItem in objShopOnlineDBEntities.Items
                               select new SelectListItem()
                               {
                                   Text = "<Item Text>",
                                   Value = objItem.ItemId.ToString(),
                                   Selected = true
                               })
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed how you said and now is saying to me : Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ItemViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ListItemId' and no extension method 'ListItemId' accepting a first argument of type 'ItemViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImagePath { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListItemId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectListItem { get; set; }

    }
}    `

Comment: I have `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListItemId { get; set; }`  i don't know why is saying i don't have it . Maybe because i have `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectListItem { get; set; } ` and are two on same ViewModel is the problem?

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds weird. Are your `@model ItemViewModel` is refer to the `ItemViewModel` class that you attached? I suspect that there are multiple classes with the same name `ItemViewModel` and in your View, you refer to the wrong `ItemViewModel` class.

Comment: I have only one @model ItemViewModel that i think is weird yes.    https://github.com/Raf27/ShopOnline  this is the GitHub repo were i uploaded the application. It would be nice if i can solve it because tomorow i need to present it at my university !

Comment: While, I commented those seem aspx code (textbox.Text) in ItemController in order to build the project success.